# Is there an idiom or slang word for "the last round of beer"?

Tags: slang, idiom-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase that would fit here, where a few guys are drinking at a pub.

- A. "I must be going now."
- B. "Hey, wait, let's have ..............."

which would mean a final drink before driving home.

Comment: one for the road.

Comment: Last call: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_call_(bar_term)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*One for the road* is the usual phrase.

It isn't just used in a pub, it is used when offering a visitor a final drink before leaving.

It is becoming less commonly used as drinking and driving is becoming less common.

Comment: I'm trying hard not to downvote (I upvoted medica's earlier identical answering).